# Custom action Error in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, custom-action

I have a controller called TextController,I created a custom action in my controller called trans controller which I used to manage multi languages.The problem arises when I submit the form.It shows me that  **Not Found (#404)
The requested page does not exist.**
I confused with this...Can anybody help me????
I am attaching my controller and view here.
**My Controller**

```
public function actionTranslate()
{
    // echo 'dddddddddd';die();

     for($x = 0; $x < count($_POST['english']); $x++ )
{
    $model = $this->findModel($_POST['text_id'][$x]);
    $model->trans_text_id = $_POST['text_id'][$x];
    $model->trans_text_label =$_POST['label_id'][$x];
    $model->English =$_POST['english'][$x];
    $model->Spanish =$_POST['spanish'][$x];
    $model->French =$_POST['french'][$x] ;
    $model->German =$_POST['german'][$x] ; 
    // echo '<pre>';print_r($model->trans_text_id);

  $model->save(false);

}

echo Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Translation Saved');

return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->referrer);
}
```

**My Form**

```
   <?php 
   use yii\helpers\Html;
   use app\modules\admin\models\TransLabels;
   use app\modules\admin\models\TransText;

        $ids = $_GET['id'];
        // echo $ids;

        $model = TransLabels::find()->where(['trans_page_title' => $ids])->all();

                     // echo '<pre>';print_r($model);die();

     ?>


<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Labels</th>
      <th>English</th>
      <th>Spanish</th>
      <th>French</th>
      <th>German</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  <form action="<?php echo Yii::$app->homeUrl;?>admin/text/translate" method="post" >
     <?php
     if (Yii::$app->session->hasFlash('success')) {?>
        <div>
        <center><h1><span style="color:green; text-align:centre "><?php
          print_r(Yii::$app->session->getFlash('success'));
          ?> </span></h1></center>
        </div>
        <?php }
         ?>
  <?php
  foreach($model as $expertn)
    {    
    $title=$expertn['trans_labels'];
    $label_id = $expertn['trans_label_id'];
    $sql = TransText::find()->where(['trans_text_label'=>$label_id])->all();
    $eng = $sql[0]->English;
    $span = $sql[0]->Spanish;
    $fren = $sql[0]->French;
    $ger = $sql[0]->German;
    $text_id = $sql[0]->trans_text_id;
   // echo '<pre>';print_r($ger);
// echo $expertn['trans_label_id'];
        echo '<tr>'; // start a new row   
        echo '<td data-label="Payment">';
        echo $expertn['trans_labels'];
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="text_id[]" value="'.$text_id.'"/>';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="label_id[]" value="'.$expertn['trans_label_id'].'"/>';
        echo '</td>';
        echo '<td data-label="Issue Date">';
        echo '<input type="text" name="english[]" value="'.$eng.'"/>';
        echo '</td>';
        echo '<td data-label="Issue Date">';
        echo '<input type="text"name="spanish[]" value="'.$span.'"/>';
        echo '</td>';
        echo '<td data-label="Issue Date">';
        echo '<input type="text"name="french[]" value="'.$fren.'"/>';
        echo '</td>';
        echo '<td data-label="Issue Date">';
        echo '<input type="text"name="german[]" value="'.$ger.'"/>';
        echo '</td>';

        // echo '<td>';
        // echo $expertn['tcount'];
        // echo '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';

    }
        echo '<input type="submit"  name="submit" id="sub" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary bton"/>';
    ?>
</form>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Use `<form action="<?php echo Yii::$app->homeUrl;?>admin/text/translate" method="post" >` because your controller name is **TextController**. Url format should be */.../controller/action*

Comment: Thank you for all your support guys....I made missed forgot to remove the Findmodel from my create action....Now its working perfectly...

Answer (score 0):

If you are having controller named `TextController` then in **view file**

```
...
<form action="<?php echo Yii::$app->request/baseUrl;?>admin/text/translate" method="post" >
...
```

OR

```
...
<form action="<?php echo Yii::$app->homeUrl;?>/admin/text/translate" method="post" >
...
```

and in `TextController.php`

```
public function actionTranslate()
{
    // echo 'dddddddddd';die();

    for($x = 0; $x < count($_POST['english']); $x++ )
    {
        if($model = $this->findModel($_POST['text_id'][$x]))
        {
            $model->trans_text_id = $_POST['text_id'][$x];
            $model->trans_text_label =$_POST['label_id'][$x];
            $model->English =$_POST['english'][$x];
            $model->Spanish =$_POST['spanish'][$x];
            $model->French =$_POST['french'][$x] ;
            $model->German =$_POST['german'][$x] ; 
            // echo '<pre>';print_r($model->trans_text_id);

            $model->save(false);
            unset($model);            
        }
    }

    echo Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Translation Saved');

    return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->referrer);
}
```

You should put it `if` condition (because if not found in db then?) in `for` loop  and `unset` at the end of `if` condition